# Communion on the Moon

Tags: the-moon, spacesuits, food

[This](http://www.snopes.com/glurge/communion.asp) article ([and](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Buzz_Aldrin#NASA_career) some [others](http://www.hoax-slayer.com/communion-on-the-moon.shtml)) confirms "that Buzz Aldrin took communion on the surface of the moon". How is it possible that he ate and drank on the surface of the moon while wearing a space suit?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

He was in the Lunar Excursion Module (LEM) at the time! :)

Comment: Yes. Of course. :$